# web.xml in struts and how it is configured with struts-config.xml

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, netbeans, struts

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The above code was automatically generated by my IDE when I choose struts framework for my project. I don't see any servlet named *action* . Please explain what this xml means?

**EDIT :**

I read that ActionServlet has been configured with the struts-config.xml file. How it is configured ?

```
<struts-config>

<form-beans>
<form-bean name="HelloWorldActionForm"

type="com.vaannila.HelloWorldActionForm"/>

<action-mappings>
<action input="/index.jsp" name="HelloWorldActionForm" path="/HelloWorld"  scope="session" type="com.vaannila.HelloWorldAction">
<forward name="success" path="/helloWorld.jsp" />
</action>
</action-mappings>
```

Answer (score 5):

The configuration file shown says this:

- All URLs which end in `.do` will be processed by a servlet named `action`
- The servlet named `action` corresponds to the class `org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet`

Comment: I read that _ActionServlet has been configured with the struts-config.xml file_. can you explain this? see the edit

Comment: @grassPro The `ActionServlet` was configured in `web.xml`, whereas in `struts-config.xml` the different `ActionForm`s get configured; implicitly these use the `ActionServlet`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how Struts works:

Struts has a FrontController. This means all request are going through this controller. This is the org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet. This class is using the **struts-config** to pass the request to an other class.

You have specified that everytime the URL: **/HelloWorld** is request the ActionServlet is passing the request to the class **com.vaannila.HelloWorldAction** When your class is returning **success** the ActionServlet will display the jsp: **helloWorld.jsp**

Answer (score 0):

By default ActionServlet is configured to /WEB-INF/struts-config.xml file under your web application project directory.

for example: if your project name is StrutsPractice then you can find the default configuration file in the path /StrutsPractice/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml

To explicitly configure the ActionServlet or you want to configure it to a config file in a different path then you can configure it like below in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>strutspractice</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>strutspractice</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```